# Removing subviews from UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uiscrollview

I need to remove image `subviews` from a `ScrollView` and I tried removing from the `array` of `subviews` but that is an `NSArray` which is immutable.

How can a `subview` be removed from the `scrollviews array` of `subviews`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [scrollView subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) [v removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Doing so you will also remove the scroll indicators... Seems we have to check the type of the view to be removed.

Answer (score 12):

You can do this,

```
[[scrollView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Answer (score 5):

This will remove all subviews of a UIScrollView but its scroll indicators:
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [_scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    _scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator =
    _scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

Comment: Apparently `[_scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];` will remove all UIScrollView subviews, including its scroll indicators. Hiding the scroll indicators before removing all subviews from scrollview will ensure scroll indicators are not removed from scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (UIView *v in [scrollView subviews]) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call -removeFromSuperview on the subview.

Answer (score 1):

Swift

```
for subview in scrollView.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```